# Название шрифта

Tags: captcha, шрифты

Как называется шрифт для капчи?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micra

Answer (score 0):

[Sanzettica](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/aah-yes/sanzettica/heavy-expd/)?

Comment: Вроде он, но где скачать? Везде купить предлагают